# Add Action Bar Menu Item Programatically

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I want to programmatically set a new menu item on the right if the user is in a defined screen, but only if it's in this screen, not on another.

How can I do this without setting a new menu resource? In this class I'm actually changing my left menu item like that.

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.ic_back));
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Comment: If you're using `Fragment`s you can add the new item's to the fragment's menu and those items will be shown only while the fragment is attached to the activity.

Comment: @Titus I'm working with an activity..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new recource and make it invisable on other screens and make I visable on the screen you want.

Comment: In which resource? And then how can I find the view in the support action bar? I don't have the option to findViewById

Comment: You need to add item in menu resource file and then add it in you activity method